# Create bitmap for full listview with all items (Without getting 32 bit illegalArgumentException)

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I want to create bitmap (which in turn will be converted to a .png file) of a full listview inside my app. But when I get the bitmap from a listview child I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
```

**Is it somehow possible to override this behaviour?** Or do it in a way such that it doesn't get thrown?

*The reason Im asking is that I want to have a picture of this list on my website and taking screenshots would be a very tedious process (There are over 400 items in the list, and there are 6 visible on screen at a time.)*

As per request here's the code I'm running to create a bitmap atm:

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {

ListView listview = getListView();
ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter(); 
int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
int allitemsheight   = 0;
List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

    View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
    childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
    childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView.buildDrawingCache();
    bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
    allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
}

Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
int iHeight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
    Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
    bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
    iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();

    bmp.recycle();
    bmp=null;
}


return bigbitmap;
}
```

And here's the exception being thrown (Please note that this is all I got, Android Studio isn't working for me and all I could save was half the stack trace)

```
E/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6577)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please provide the code that you are using and the complete stack trace, to increase the odds that you can get help here.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my question with both code and stack trace.

Comment: I've been avoiding the drawing cache stuff after Romain Guy politely steered me away. It may be faster to write a **`uiautomator`** test case, using `takeScreenshot()` on `UiDevice` to automate the screenshot-taking, and using `pressDPadDown()` to work your way through the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure hardware-accelerated views have 48-bit color, so disabling hardware acceleration on the ListView items should fix the drawing cache. I wouldn't rely on the drawing cache to work in future releases.

Comment: wow cool, my question is how to check if hardware-accelerated views have 48-bit color or 32-bit in different device?